# Jackson error - Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: jboss, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I am getting thie below excepetion in Jackson running on JBOSS Wildfly 8.2. My Jackson versions are below. The same versions are used in the module as well.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

> Exception Details:   Location:
>       com/test/cisl/jackson/rest/CustomObjectMapper.()V @421: invokevirtual   Reason:
>       Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/JodaModule' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'   Current Frame:
>       bci: @421
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'com/test/cisl/jackson/rest/CustomObjectMapper', 'com/test/cisl/base/jackson/ClassModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule',
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule' }
>       stack: { 'com/test/cisl/jackson/rest/CustomObjectMapper', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/JodaModule' }   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ab7 0001 bb00 0259 b700 034c 2b12 0412
>       0x0000010: 05b6 0006 2b04 bd00 0759 0312 0853 b600
>       0x0000020: 09a7 0017 4dbb 000b 592c b700 0cbf 4dbb
>       0x0000030: 000b 592c b700 0cbf 2a2b b600 0e57 2ab2
>       0x0000040: 000f 03b6 0010 57bb 0011 59b7 0012 4d2c
>       0x0000050: 1213 bb00 1459 1213 b700 15b6 0016 572c
>       0x0000060: 1213 bb00 1759 1213 b700 18b6 0019 572a
>       0x0000070: 2cb6 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012 4e2d 121a
>       0x0000080: bb00 1b59 121a b700 1cb6 0016 572d 121a
>       0x0000090: bb00 1d59 121a b700 1eb6 0019 572a 2db6
>       0x00000a0: 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012 3a04 1904 121f
>       0x00000b0: bb00 2059 121f b700 21b6 0016 5719 0412
>       0x00000c0: 1fbb 0022 5912 1fb7 0023 b600 1957 2a19
>       0x00000d0: 04b6 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012 3a05 1905
>       0x00000e0: 1224 bb00 2559 1224 b700 26b6 0016 5719
>       0x00000f0: 0512 24bb 0027 5912 24b7 0028 b600 1957
>       0x0000100: 2a19 05b6 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012 3a06
>       0x0000110: 1906 1229 bb00 2a59 1229 b700 2bb6 0016
>       0x0000120: 5719 0612 29bb 002c 5912 29b7 002d b600
>       0x0000130: 1957 2a19 06b6 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012
>       0x0000140: 3a07 1907 122e bb00 2f59 122e b700 30b6
>       0x0000150: 0019 572a 1907 b600 0e57 bb00 1159 b700
>       0x0000160: 123a 0819 0812 31bb 0032 5912 31b7 0033
>       0x0000170: b600 1657 1908 1234 bb00 3559 1234 b700
>       0x0000180: 36b6 0016 5719 0812 37bb 0038 5912 37b7
>       0x0000190: 0039 b600 1657 2a19 08b6 000e 572a bb00
>       0x00001a0: 3a59 b700 3bb6 000e 57bb 0011 59b7 0012
>       0x00001b0: 3a09 1909 123c bb00 3d59 123c b700 3eb6
>       0x00001c0: 0016 5719 0912 3cbb 003f 5912 3cb7 0040
>       0x00001d0: b600 1957 2a19 09b6 000e 572a b200 41b6
>       0x00001e0: 0042 572a b200 43b6 0044 572a b200 45b6
>       0x00001f0: 0046 57b1                                 Exception Handler Table:
>       bci [12, 33] => handler: 36
>       bci [12, 33] => handler: 46   Stackmap Table:
>       full_frame(@36,{Object[#100],Object[#101]},{Object[#102]})
>       same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@46,Object[#103])
>       same_frame(@56)
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
> ```

Comment: Can you try marking those dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>`? You may be ending up with two different versions on your class path.

Comment: yeah.. tried that..no luck.. same error

Comment: Did you find a way around this issue in the end?